# How to disconnect ceiling joists from wall to raise them for wall repair

Tags: framing, ceiling, roof, frame

I have to repair support wall framing. I will rent ceiling jacks. What is the best way to separate the joists from the wall top plate? I can't raise them while nailed to the top plate, and I don't see how to get a sawzall in between there to cut the nails. Maybe use jacks for upward pressure and pry them apart just enough for room for the blade?

Comment: Sounds like an idea.  The blade is not that thick(1/16) and usually you only want enough to cut, when lifting/jacking building parts.  One time where less is best.

Comment: Why can't you raise the joists while they're nailed to the top plate? At the very least relieve the pressure with jacking and then use your recip saw. If a gap opens in the wrong spot and you don't want to lose a kerf of wall height, then a pry bar can open the gap that you want once the jacking has opened a gap somewhere. I would just go nuts with the jacking and worry about cutting nails as an afterthought. If there's drywall/sheathing down low, that will restrain the studs from opening a gap at the bottom plate. Don't forget the sheathing nails into the top plate from the outside.

Comment: @crip659 or maybe an oscillating multitool with a blade for metals?